# GridView only displays information from the first row

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have two GridViews. One just displays the date and the user and the second one displays a list with a checkbox next to each item.

I've made the date in the gridview a link to view the second gridview so the user can see which items were ticked. The problem is it only displays the information from the first row even though I selected the second row. 
[image]

See in the image I clicked the second row in the top GridView. But the information that is displayed in the second GridView isn't the row I clicked. It should be showing the information for ID 395545

I have found the problem is with postback:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
           List<lookupCVRT> work = lookupCVRT.GetCVRTItems(Company.Current.CompanyID, ParentID.ToString());


                ViewState["CVRT"] = work;
                gvCVRT.DataSource = work;
                gvCVRT.DataBind();

                if (work.Count > 0)
                {
                    string numberToView = gvCVRT.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;

                    List<lookupCVRT> workDetails = lookupCVRT.GetChecklistItemsByChecklistID(Company.Current.CompanyID, ParentID.ToString(), numberToView.ToString());
                    gvCVRTDetails.DataSource = workDetails;
                    gvCVRTDetails.DataBind();
                } 
         }
    }
```

This code loads the information for the first GridView then based on the ID in this GridView, it loads the second GridView. The problem is it only loads the ID of the first row. So when it binds the second GridView it is only looking at the first ID.

Is there a way to force postback so the second Grid reloads for the ID of the row I select?

Here's the GridView codes:

```
<div id="divCVRT">
    <fieldset class="groupbox" >                               
        <div style="width:100%;">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpCVRT" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView  style="width:75%"  
                        ID="gvCVRT" 
                        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                        CssClass="tblResults" 
                        runat="server" 
                        OnRowDataBound="gvCVRT_RowDataBound"                             
                        DataKeyField="ID" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        allowpaging="false"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ChecklistID" HeaderText="ID" ></asp:BoundField> 
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ChecklistDate" HeaderText="Checklist Date" dataformatstring="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="User" HeaderText="User" ></asp:BoundField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>  
            <asp:LinkButton title="Add CVRT" id="btnAddCVRT" OnClick="btnAddCVRT_Click" runat="server" style="cursor:pointer;">
                <img src="../images/icons/buttons/basic1-072.png" />
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="divCVRTDetails" style="display:none">
    <fieldset class="groupbox" >                               
        <div style="width:100%;">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpCVRTDetails" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView  style="width:75%"  
                        ID="gvCVRTDetails" 
                        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                        CssClass="tblResults" 
                        runat="server" 
                        OnRowDataBound="gvCVRTDetails_RowDataBound"                             
                        DataKeyField="ID" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        allowpaging="false"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ChecklistID" HeaderText="ID" ></asp:BoundField> 
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Checklist Items"></asp:BoundField> 
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Checked?" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChecked" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdateCVRT" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddCVRT" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdateCVRT" OnClientClick="CloseAddEditCVRT()"  OnClick="btnUpdateCVRT_Click" runat="server" style="float:left" CssClass="btnSaveSmall" ></asp:LinkButton>
            <a title="Close CVRT Details" id="btnCloseCVRTDetails" runat="server" class="btnCancelSmall" style="cursor:pointer; margin-left:40px">
            </a>  
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

code behind child gridview:

```
protected void gvCVRTDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            lookupCVRT work = (lookupCVRT)e.Row.DataItem;
            GridView gv = sender as GridView;



            e.Row.Attributes.Add("ID", "gvCVRTDetails_" + work.ID);
            e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("onclick", "event.stopPropagation();");

            HtmlGenericControl lnkShowHide = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Row.FindControl("lnkShowHide");
            HyperLink ChecklistItem = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("ID");

            CheckBox chkChecked = e.Row.FindControl("chkChecked") as CheckBox;

            chkChecked.Attributes.Add("onclick", "UpdateCheckedBox(" + work.ID.ToString() + ", this.value);");

            chkChecked.Checked = work.Checked;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't bind the child GridView with any select action on the parent GridView, this is why it will not display anything. the code you wrote on Page Load will always bind with first item of the parent.

To fix this you need to handle the OnSelectedIndexChanged of the parent GridView and then bind the child GridView depend on the selected ID

see the updated code (I removed the Ajax code, so it Post back to page again):

```
<div id="divCVRT">
    <fieldset class="groupbox" >                               
        <div style="width:100%;">
                <asp:GridView  style="width:75%"  
                        ID="gvCVRT" 
                        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                        CssClass="tblResults" 
                        runat="server" 
                        OnRowDataBound="gvCVRT_RowDataBound"                             
                        DataKeyField="ID"
                        DataKeyNames="ID"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        allowpaging="false"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ChecklistID" HeaderText="ID" ></asp:BoundField> 
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ChecklistDate" HeaderText="Checklist Date" dataformatstring="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="User" HeaderText="User" ></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
            <asp:LinkButton title="Add CVRT" id="btnAddCVRT" OnClick="btnAddCVRT_Click" runat="server" style="cursor:pointer;">
                <img src="../images/icons/buttons/basic1-072.png" />
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="divCVRTDetails" style="display:none">
    <fieldset class="groupbox" >                               
        <div style="width:100%;">
                <asp:GridView  style="width:75%"  
                        ID="gvCVRTDetails" 
                        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                        CssClass="tblResults" 
                        runat="server" 
                        OnRowDataBound="gvCVRTDetails_RowDataBound"                             
                        DataKeyField="ID" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        allowpaging="false"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ChecklistID" HeaderText="ID" ></asp:BoundField> 
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Checklist Items"></asp:BoundField> 
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Checked?" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChecked" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdateCVRT" OnClientClick="CloseAddEditCVRT()"  OnClick="btnUpdateCVRT_Click" runat="server" style="float:left" CssClass="btnSaveSmall" ></asp:LinkButton>
            <a title="Close CVRT Details" id="btnCloseCVRTDetails" runat="server" class="btnCancelSmall" style="cursor:pointer; margin-left:40px"></a>  
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

then in code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        List<lookupCVRT> work = lookupCVRT.GetCVRTItems(Company.Current.CompanyID, ParentID.ToString());
        gvCVRT.DataSource = work;
        gvCVRT.DataBind();
     }
}

protected void gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<lookupCVRT> workDetails = lookupCVRT.GetChecklistItemsByChecklistID(Company.Current.CompanyID, ParentID.ToString(), gvCVRT.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString());
    gvCVRTDetails.DataSource = workDetails;
    gvCVRTDetails.DataBind();
}
```

**Update:**
this is minimal example to get the idea:
Department is the parent table, and categories is the child table

```
<div>
            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="ParentGridView"
                DataKeyNames="DepartmentId" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ParentGridView_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartmentId" HeaderText="DepartmentId"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartmentName" HeaderText="DepartmentName"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartmentDescription" HeaderText="DepartmentDescription"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

            <br />
            <br />

            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="ChildGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="CategoryName"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryDescription" HeaderText="CategoryDescription"></asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

the code behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                var data = db.Departments.ToList();

                ParentGridView.DataSource = data;
                ParentGridView.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void ParentGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int key = int.Parse(ParentGridView.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString());

            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var data = db.Categories.Where(p => p.DepartmentId == key);

            ChildGridView.DataSource = data;
            ChildGridView.DataBind();
        }
```

and it should work as you want.

Comment: thanks for the code. But I get an error in the gridviewParent_SelectedIndexChanged function on gvCVRT.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString(): the Data keys must be specified on GridView 'gvCVRT' before the selected data keys can be retrieved.  Use the DataKeyNames property to specify data keys.

Comment: I update the answer, you need to add DataKeyNames="ID" on the first GridView. and it should work now

Comment: Yes that got rid of the error but the child grid isn't showing

Comment: Is there something else I need to add?

Comment: I have added another example, it should work. if you still have problem then put breakpoint on the method _SelectedIndexChanged and trace for that point to see what is the issue.

Comment: I put a breakpoint into the method. After that method it jumps to the gvCVRTDetails_RowDataBound function. I put the code for this in my question. Does something need to be added to this function?

Comment: you could remove gvCVRTDetails_RowDataBound  method from the gridview, do you have any special action on it?

Comment: I need this method. It links to a web method for the checkboxes: chkChecked.Attributes.Add("onclick", "UpdateCheckedBox(" + work.ID.ToString() + ", this.value);");. I tried removing this method to see if it solved my problem but it didn't. The grid still doesn't display